# Creating a UIView that captures taps, but is transparent to all other gestures

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, uiscrollview, gestures

I want to achieve the following.

Scenario: The iOS keyboard is on-screen while the user is typing into a particular text field. The user can tap anywhere outside of the keyboard and text field to dismiss the keyboard (without activating any buttons which are visible). Also, the user can *drag* outside of the keyboard and observe the normal drag behavior on some arrangement of scrollable views.

Conceptually, I’m placing a “cover” `UIView` over most of the screen which behaves such that:

1. If the user taps on the cover, then I capture that tap (so that I can, e.g., dismiss the keyboard). This is easy to achieve by intercepting touch events in a `UIView` subclass or using a tap gesture recognizer.
2. If the user drags on the cover, then the cover *ignores* or *forwards* these touches; these are received by the layers underneath just as they would have been without a cover.

So: the user should be able to scroll content underneath the cover, but not tap content underneath the cover. A tap “outside” of the keyboard and text field should dismiss the keyboard (and cover), but should not activate anything.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have to consider implementing the touches delegate method and pass on the touches to the views which are behind it for swiping.

`- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*) touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
   [otherView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}` Another way is to implement, UIPanGestureRecognizer and set cancelsTouchesInView = YES as `UIPanGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan)];
        [gr setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
        [myButton addGestureRecognizer:gr];
        [gr release];`

Answer (score 2):

Add the tap gesture the usual way:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

But what you may be looking for is this :

```
    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
    {    
        return YES;
    }
```

Documentation says : This method is called when recognition of a gesture by either gestureRecognizer or otherGestureRecognizer would block the other gesture recognizer from recognizing its gesture. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate)

This way, you may be sure it's totally transparent, and also that nothing will prevent your recognizer from being called.

Answer (score 1):

A custom view which forwards all touches it receives:

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        var hitView = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)

        if hitView == self {
            return nil
        }

        return hitView
    }    
}
```

From there you can go different ways to just make use of tap gestures. Either observe the UIEvent for its touches, or use a gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

**1: Add a tap gesture recognizer to the view:**

```
    //Adding tap gesture
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

**2: In handleTapGesture you resignFirstResponder of the keyboard**

```
- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {
       //Resign first responder for keyboard here
    }
}
```

Elaborated a bit on the answer above. UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized makes sure it's single tab events that gets recognized.

Is this the functionality you where after?

Comment: His question is "if the user drags on the cover, then the cover ignores all touches; these are received by the layers underneath just as they would have been without a cover.". He has already figured out how to detect touch.

Comment: If the `UIView` is able to recognize taps, then its `.userInteractionEnabled` must be `YES` and it therefore eats all touch events, preventing drags from being recognized by whatever is underneath.